# How do I keep 'indent' from moving curly braces to the next line?

Tags: text-processing, c, programming, indentation

I have several empty inline function definitions in C++ like so:

```
class C
{
    void foo(){}
    void bar(){}
};
```

now if I run `indent -st -i4 -nut test.cc` in order to just fix the indentation I get

```
class C
{
    void foo ()
    {
    }
    void bar ()
    {
    }
};
```

But I just want to fix the indentation without moving curly braces around!

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at `man indent` I see using `-brf` will put braces on the function definition line. If you want it on the `if-line` as well, you'll need `-br`.

If your `PAGER` environment variable is `less` you can search through `man indent` with `/` and the text. So if you do `man indent`, followed by `/braces<ENTER>` You'll be able to hop between matches that are informative to you by pressing `n` repeated.

**Edit** to make my comment below clearer, this is what I see in `man indent`

```
The `-brf´ option formats braces like this:

        int one(void) {
          return 1;
        };

The `-blf´ option formats them like this:

        int one(void)
        {
          return 1;
        };
```

Comment: `-brf` will put the closing brace in the next line. What I want is that indent leaves all braces alone...

Comment: @steffen the documentation says you're wrong `-brf, --braces-on-func-def-line // Put braces on function definition line.`

Comment: that's right, the short explanation is misleading. Scroll down to section DECLARATIONS and find the long explanation.

Comment: On all the different variants of linux (and versions of those) I have access to the section you reference has been edited into my original answer.

Comment: Yep, that's what I found. I would like that indent left the braces alone alltogether but that seems not to be possible. I'll accept your answer anyway because your answer is comprehensive (and you were the only one to bother ;) ) Thanks.

Comment: I can't seem to reproduce your behavior. `-brf` works for me. Sorry.